# Unsure why this code is causing unresponsive pages when trying to load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, while-loop, infinite-loop

So Im building a music streaming app and im trying to have this algorithm pick only 3 and to insure that none are duplicates, Im unsure whats going wrong maybe an infinite loop ? is there a better way ? appreciate all the help.

```
randomThree() {
    let { songs } = this.props;
    let otherSongs = [];

    while (otherSongs.length < 3) {
      let randSong = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
      if (!otherSongs.includes(randSong)) {
        otherSongs.push(randSong);
      }
    }

    this.setState({ moresongs: otherSongs });
  }
```

Comment: What's the structure of a song in `songs` array ?

Comment: Add some `console.log` statements to start helping you debug. Finding out if you're in an infinite loop should be easy if you print each time inside the loop. Print the value of `songs` to make sure you have what you think you do. Print `otherSongs` before setting the state, etc.

Comment: Thank you both it turns out that on the first load it only has one song in the array so it just keep looping !